# libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos, centos6, drivers, nvidia

I'm having problems using the nouveau driver for my Nvidia GeForce 9100. 
Xorg starts up and works fine, I am able to use everything, although in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` I have:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep EE
[    36.166] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[    36.166] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

and when I run glxinfo or glxgears from shell I get

```
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so failed (/usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
```

but the dmesg reveal that the driver is loaded

```
$ dmesg | grep nouveau

nouveau 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
nouveau 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> Link[SGRU] -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] BOOT0  : 0x0aa380a2
nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Chipset: MCP77/MCP78 (NVAA)
nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:02:00.0] Family : NV50
nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:02:00.0] checking PRAMIN for image...
nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:02:00.0] ... appears to be valid
nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:02:00.0] using image from PRAMIN
nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:02:00.0] BIT signature found
nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:02:00.0] version 62.77.2f.00.06
nouveau  [     PFB][0000:02:00.0] RAM type: stolen system memory
nouveau  [     PFB][0000:02:00.0] RAM size: 256 MiB
nouveau  [     PFB][0000:02:00.0]    ZCOMP: 0 tags
nouveau  [    VOLT][0000:02:00.0] GPU voltage: 1100000uv
nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:02:00.0] FAN control: none / external
nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:02:00.0] fan management: automatic
nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:02:00.0] internal sensor: yes
nouveau  [     CLK][0000:02:00.0] 0f: core 500 MHz shader 1200 MHz vdec 500 MHz
nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:02:00.0] temperature (103 C) hit the 'critical' threshold
nouveau  [     CLK][0000:02:00.0] --: core 350 MHz shader 1600 MHz vdec 350 MHz
nouveau  [     DRM] VRAM: 256 MiB
nouveau  [     DRM] GART: 1048576 MiB
nouveau  [     DRM] TMDS table version 2.0
nouveau  [     DRM] DCB version 4.0
nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 00: 01000300 0000001e
nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 01: 01011332 00020010
nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 00: 00000100
nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 01: 00001231
nouveau  [     DRM] MM: using M2MF for buffer copies
nouveau 0000:02:00.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
nouveau  [     DRM] allocated 1024x768 fb: 0x50000, bo ffff880217493000
fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
nouveau 0000:02:00.0: registered panic notifier
[drm] Initialized nouveau 1.1.1 20120801 for 0000:02:00.0 on minor 0
```

My system specs: CentOS release 6.6 (Final), 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C78 [GeForce 9100] (rev a2)
```

I installed and removed the Nvidia proprietary drivers several times so there might be something wrong with libraries and whatnots.
It looks to me like the system is looking for `/usr/lib64/dri/nouveau_dri.so` while it shouldn't. To my knowledge, there is no CentOS 6 package that provides that file.

Any help will be very appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nvidia proprietary driver crashes CentOS 6.6](http://serverfault.com/questions/699713/nvidia-proprietary-driver-crashes-centos-6-6)

Comment: @JennyD It is related to that question since it is the same machine, but I decided to ask two different questions because it is about two different drivers. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Leo Sorry; i should have been more careful in my reading. But in either case, the question doesn't belong on this site. You could try on [unix.se] - not because they are "friendlier", but because your questions are a better match for that site.